# Flask context variable not available in template

Tags: flask, jinja2, python-3.6

New to Flask and trying to work on a tutorial but running into some problems with the context variable from `render_template()` method.

Here is `app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

posts = [
    {
        'author': 'Some Author',
        'title': 'Blog Post 1',
        'content': 'First blog post',
        'date_posted': 'April 21, 2018'
    },
    {
        'author': 'Another Author',
        'title': 'Blog Post 2',
        'content': 'Second blog post',
        'date_posted': 'May 21, 2013'
    }
]


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)


@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And this is my `home.html` template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    { % for post in posts % }
        <h4>{{ post.title }}</h4>
        <p>By {{ post.author }} on {{ post.date_posted }}</p>
        <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    { % endfor % }
</body>
</html>
```

But the above isn't working.
In browser at top of the page I get,

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'post' is undefined
```

Here is the traceback from the terminal as well:

```
File "/home/bigdaddy/Sites/Flask_Blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/bigdaddy/Sites/Flask_Blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/bigdaddy/Sites/Flask_Blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/bigdaddy/Sites/Flask_Blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/bigdaddy/Sites/Flask_Blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/bigdaddy/Sites/Flask_Blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/bigdaddy/Sites/Flask_Blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/bigdaddy/Sites/Flask_Blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/bigdaddy/Sites/Flask_Blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/bigdaddy/Sites/Flask_Blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/bigdaddy/Sites/Flask_Blog/app.py", line 25, in home
    return render_template('home.html', some_list=posts)
  File "/home/bigdaddy/Sites/Flask_Blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 135, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "/home/bigdaddy/Sites/Flask_Blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 117, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/home/bigdaddy/Sites/Flask_Blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bigdaddy/Sites/Flask_Blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/home/bigdaddy/Sites/Flask_Blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/bigdaddy/Sites/Flask_Blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/bigdaddy/Sites/Flask_Blog/templates/home.html", line 8, in top-level template code
    <h4>{{ post.title }}</h4>
  File "/home/bigdaddy/Sites/Flask_Blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 430, in getattr
    return getattr(obj, attribute)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'post' is undefined
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Using python3.6 in a virtualenv on Xubuntu Linux 16.04 if that helps.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jinja isn't detecting your for loop because you have put a space between `{` and `%` and Jinja is looking for the specific pair `{%`. Right now Jinja is completely ignoring the `{ % for post in posts % }` line, treating as part of the HTML it doesn't have to do anything with and moving onto the next one, where it's failing to find `post`.

The following fixes the start and end of the loop:

```
<body>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <h4>{{ post.title }}</h4>
        <p>By {{ post.author }} on {{ post.date_posted }}</p>
        <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Implementing the above as you suggested worked in the sense that I'm no longer receiving those errors but now in the browser, I only have a blank page. No data is being rendered. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Seeing as this resolved the error message, it would be best to accept the answer and ask another question to keep things clear for others who look at this question in the future.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'd look at the flask logs and see which template it's calling from where. A blank page generally means no content. Try putting some text that is independent of the posts variable on the page and see if that loads.

Comment: Actually, the space between `{` and '%` doesn't matter, @J2112O your code is work, i have test it on my computer with Python 2.7. and Python3.6 also work for me.

Comment: @ Frank AK. It is strange behavior and maybe something on my setup/environment. For, with those spaces, my app does not work and only produces the errors I originally posted in the question. Yet removing them does work.

Comment: The Jinja templating docs specify `{%` as the correct symbol pair for computations, it's generally safer to follow the official docs on these things. http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#synopsis

Comment: @ Nevelina A. After restarting server and opening fresh page in the browser, my template is rendering the context variables correctly so I am accepting your answer since it does fix my problem as of now. Thanks for all your help.